Integrating USB and TPS62933 Buck Converter for ESP32
I'm working on a schematic for an ESP32 project, using a 6V battery pack as the primary source and the TPS62933 buck converter to step down to 3.3V. I’d also like to add a USB-B Micro input (5V) to the buck converter as a secondary power option for powering the ESP32. The USB’s D+ and D- lines are connected to the ESP32 for data transmission.
I'm really new to PCB design, what’s the best approach to integrate the USB to the buck converter in my schematic.
I'm using the TPS62933 chip. The datasheet can be found here:  https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps62933.pdf?ts=1731236381291. A typical application schematic is shown on page 28. My schematic looks as follows:

ESP32 Schematic:


You have shorted USB VBUS 5V to 3.3V net. It is damaging to both the ESP32 and will back-feed 3.3V to your PC.

Of course you can do it in so many ways but this is the simpliest way i guess:
You just simply add a diode between USB VBUS (VCC in your scenerio) and 6V input. To make it clear; Diode's anode to J1's Pin 1 and diode's cathode to JC1's Pin 2. Also remove the ferride bead FB1. It's shorting 5V and 3V3. Simply remove FB1 and C5 and add a diode.
